# multiple ssl sites one ip nginx centos

Tags: nginx

This is a strang issue i'm having before I migrated to a beefier server I was able to host multiple ssl sites over one ip using nginx now when i enable ssl on any two sites it breaks and i get a certificate error.

Here is the first config:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  # listen on both hosts
  server_name domain.org www.domain.org;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  include h5bp/directive-only/ssl.conf;

  # and redirect to the https host (declared below)
  # avoiding http://www -> https://www -> https:// chain.
  return 301 https://domain.org$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl ;

  # listen on the wrong host
  server_name thefifthdown.org;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.error.log;
  include h5bp/directive-only/ssl.conf;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/site.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/site.key;
  # and redirect to the non-www host (declared below)
  return 301 https://dommain.org$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl ;

  # The host name to respond to
  server_name domain.org;

  include h5bp/directive-only/ssl.conf;

  # Path for static files
  root /var/www/root;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
  #Specify a charset
  charset utf-8;

location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }
  # Custom 404 page
  error_page 404 /404.html;

  # Include the basic h5bp config set
  include h5bp/basic.conf;
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
gzip on;
gzip_types text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon;
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC CDN
location ~ \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$ {
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
}
# END W3TC CDN
rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;

  location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                 }
}


second site


server {
  listen 80;

  # listen on both hosts
  server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  include h5bp/directive-only/ssl.conf;

  # and redirect to the https host (declared below)
  # avoiding http://www -> https://www -> https:// chain.
  return 301 https://domain2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy;

  # listen on the wrong host
  server_name www.domain2.com;

  include h5bp/directive-only/ssl.conf;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/site2.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/site2.come.key;
  # and redirect to the non-www host (declared below)
  return 301 https://domain2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy;

  # The host name to respond to
  server_name domain2.com;

   include h5bp/directive-only/ssl.conf;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/site2.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site2.error.log;
  # Path for static files
  root /var/www/root2;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
  #Specify a charset
  charset utf-8;

location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }
  # Custom 404 page
  error_page 404 /404.html;

  # Include the basic h5bp config set
  include h5bp/basic.conf;
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
gzip on;
gzip_types text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon;
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC CDN
location ~ \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$ {
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
}
# END W3TC CDN
rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;

  location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                 }
}



nginx version: nginx/1.6.1
built by gcc 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-google_perftools_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-E'
```

Does anyone have a clue what i'm missing? been working on this all night and i'm sure it's something simple

Comment: `when I enable ssl on any two sites it breaks and I get a certificate error`. This doesn't look like being a problem with "multiple sites" but with "ssl certificate". Did you check whether `/etc/nginx/ssl/site.crt`, `/etc/nginx/ssl/site2.crt`, `/etc/nginx/ssl/site.key`, `/etc/nginx/ssl/site2.come.key` are still on the old server?

Comment: yes I did. I even reissued both certs. still no luck.

Comment: You have mistyped your domain name several different ways in this configuration and made a lot of other typos. Try correcting these first.

Comment: Can you add more detail on the error you receive, or some relevant log?

Comment: the typos in the config pasted above was just a bad attempt at obfuscation. but as for the specific error this is from firefox

Comment: ryankdjones.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: thefifthdown.org, www.thefifthdown.org (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

As for logs the GET request never makes it to the server so there's nothing in the logs to share

Comment: I fixed the issue I was following https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/tree/master/h5bp and there are some options in there that don't seem to work using only one IP.

Answer (score 0):

1. You seem to have defined ssl_certificates for the 'wrong hosts' but not the right ones. Attempting to connect over SSL to servers not having certificates defined won't succeed...
2. If the redirection `HTTP` -> `HTTPS` works as intended, please remove those snippets from your configuration.
3. Try also to strip as much comments as possible to remove fat from it.
4. Remove all unecessary parts such as caching/dynamic backend communication and replace those by simple static content for tests purposes. You may wish to use the default index.html fil provided by nginx in `/usr/share/nginx/html`.